# Jquery - Too Much recursion

Tags: php, jquery

Getting this error with jquery & jquery.form. Site has been live for awhile..upgraded to latest version of jquery & jquery form and still having same issue.

This is the error in firebug

too much recursion
[Break on this error] (function(){var l=this,g,y=l.jQuery,p=l....each(function(){o.dequeue(this,E)})}});\n

And in IE8 it's a popup error that says "Stack Overflow: Line 12"

Here's the url to the website. Any idea what part of our jquery code could be causing this?

http://www.caromalcolours.com/

thanks

Comment: use firebug to see the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `document.ready` inside `document.ready` on line 331:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // omitted some lines...

    // This is causing the infinite recursion here!!!!!!!
    $(function() { 
        $("ul#newsScroller").liScroll(); 
    }); 

    fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: I removed that and it's still giving the same error?

I updated

$(function() { 
        $("ul#newsScroller").liScroll(); 
    }); 

To this

$("ul#newsScroller").liScroll(); 

And still same error? Did I update the wrong thing?

thanks

Comment: Definitely seems to be something specific to the homepage because it doesn't happen on any page other than the homepage. Please let me know if you see anything that's causing the infinite recursion. 

Ex: http://www.caromalcolours.com/see.php

Comment: actually...Firefox seems to look good now, but still getting the stack overflow Line 12 error in ie8. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it...problem was with liScroll plugin. Update the scrolling to use something else and that fixed it. 
thanks!